# How to avoid adding extra fields in graphql query built in Relay.createcontainer?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

I am writing a UI application in reactjs and want to get data to render using graphql. I am using Relay for the same. However, the graphql query I built in Relay.createContainer is adding extra "id" field. Is there a way in relay/graphql to exclude these unnecessary fields, and include only what is given in query while creating. Below is the code snippet:
In RelayRoute.jsx::

```
TPRelayRoute.queries = {
    enterprise: () => {
        return Relay.QL`
          query etp_ptp{
            enterprise
          }`;
    }
};
```

In UITable.jsx::

```
export default Relay.createContainer(UITable, {
      initialVariables: {
          count: 20
      },
      fragments: {
          enterprise: () => {
                return Relay.QL`
            fragment etp on Enterprise {
              etpInfo{
                erInfo{
                  payments(first:$count){
                    edges{
                      node{
                        enterprise{
                          id
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }`;
          }
      }
  });
```

Query which is being sent:
{"query":"query etp_ptp {enterprise {***id***,...F0}} fragment F0 on Enterprise {etpInfo {erInfo {***paymentsEEVLi***:payments(first:20) {edges {node {enterprise{id,__typename},id,__typename},cursor},pageInfo {hasNextPage,hasPreviousPage}}}},***id***}","variables":{}}

Query expected to be sent:
{"query":"query etp_ptp {enterprise {...F0}} fragment F0 on Enterprise {etpInfo {erInfo {payments(first:20) {edges {node {enterprise{id,__typename},id,__typename},cursor},pageInfo {hasNextPage,hasPreviousPage}}}}}","variables":{}}

Answer (score 0):

Relay requires a (globally unique!) ID field to be able to distinguish between records in its local store. If the backend cannot supply this then Relay will not be able to function correctly.